# Forcing label text into one line using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, labeling, vbscript

I've encountered this problem where my labels are split between two or three lines, making them quite tall instead of wide.

Is there a way to force them into one line?

For instance, I have:

```
9.
Skorochód-Majewskiego
24
```

And I'd like to turn it into:

```
 9. Skorochód-Majewskiego 24
```

The label expression (in VBScript) I've used is `[IDlokalu] & ". " & [Adres]`, where *IDlokalu* is the first number (*9*, text field), while *adres* is the rest of the label (*Skorochód-Majewskiego 24*, short field).

[image: The label is split in two or three lines.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to fitting strategy and untick *Stack labels*.

[image: Labelling]